# Is a porch temporarily roofed with just tar paper likely to be damaged by rain?

Tags: roof, construction, porch

General Contractor has been hired to build a wrap around porch onto our house. He has most of the construction completed (decking, columns, soffits, etc) but still has not shingled the roof.  It’s just plywood and tar paper. We have had lots of rain. Will this be a problem in the future and why has he not shingled it yet?

Answer (score 4):

As long as the tar paper doesn’t get ripped up it will be fine. Even if the paper or felt is damaged it can be repaired or replaced and a little water on the plywood won’t be a problem long term.

Comment: As for why it hasn't been done yet - as stated, the tar paper does a good enough job.  There's just no rush to get it done.  Roofers are loud and get in the way of other people doing work.  It's probably easier to let everyone else finish then call in the noisy guys.

Comment: I should have said this and there will be less foot traffic on a new roof extending the life of the roof by waiting for it to get completed. Longer roof life, having entire porch roofed in 1 setup also saves you $ +

Comment: And if the construction workers are still having to get onto the roof for any reason you want that over with before shingles. Foot traffic is hard on shingles. Also there may be more roofing work than local guys can keep up with right now.